# How do I define custom eventargs for an event?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

I would like to create custom Eventargs for a series of events. I am using a third party X/Y scope where I plot Strength vs frequency.  This scope has the ability to place "Markers" on it which are just little triangles at various frequencies.  These markers support events such as when the mouse enters the marker, a click is performed, and the mouse leaves the marker.  So for two markers, here is the code:

```
        private void createEvents()
        {
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[0].Click += new EventHandler(Marker0_Click);
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[0].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Marker0_Enter);
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[0].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Marker0_Leave);

            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[1].Click += new EventHandler(Marker1_Click);
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[1].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Marker1_Enter);
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[1].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Marker1_Leave);
        }
        // And now the event handlers

        private void Marker0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something;           
        }

        private void Marker0_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              //do something          
        }

        private void Marker0_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }

        private void Marker1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something;           
        }

        private void Marker1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)      
        {
              //do something          
        }

        private void Marker1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }
```

Now this is fine for two markers....but I need 80 of them.  I could just write the whole thing out but there has to be a better way.  So I started like this:

```
    private void createMarkerEvents()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
        {
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[i].Click += new EventHandler(Marker_Click);
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Marker_Enter);
            this.scope2.MarkerGroups[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Marker_Leave);
        }
     }

        private void Marker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do something;           
        }

        private void Marker_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              //do something          
        }

        private void Marker_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }
```

So the question is how can I pass the actual marker number from the events to the event handlers?
There has got to be a way.
Thanks, Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to identify marker group you may cast `object sender` to a `MarkerGroup` object

```
private void AnyMarker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MarkerGroup group = (MarkerGroup)sender;
    int indexOfMarkerGroup = this.scope2.MarkerGroups.IndexOf(group);
    //do something;           
}
```

**OFF**: *You should define a custom EventArgs class:*

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int MyCustomProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Then use it in your event:

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ButtonPressed;
```

Fire event using custom args:

```
if(ButtonPressed != null)
{
    ButtonPressed(this, new MyEventArgs { MyCustomProperty = 1 });
}
```

**EDIT**
Full example:

```
private void createMarkerEvents()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 80; i++)
    {
        this.scope2.MarkerGroups[i].Click += new EventHandler(Marker_Click);
        this.scope2.MarkerGroups[i].MouseEnter += new EventHandler(Marker_Enter);
        this.scope2.MarkerGroups[i].MouseLeave += new EventHandler(Marker_Leave);
    }
 }

 private void Marker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     // When markergroup fires and event, it passes reference to itself as `sender` parameter
     // so we can get access it
     MarkerGroup mg = (MarkerGroup)sender; // this marker has fired a click event
     // Now you know which marker has fired event
     // if you want to determine it's index in MarkerGroups collection:
     int index = this.scope2.MarkerGroup.IndexOf(mg);

     // now you know MarkerGroup and it's index
 }

 private void Marker_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    //do something          
 }

 private void Marker_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    // do something
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.but I'm quite a beginner.So the first way I haven't a clue how to get it to work and the second how do I go from my code to what you suggest?